# How to stop the button's command by clicking another button

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say I have button1 which repeatedly changes its position randomly when clicked. I want to have button2 which will stop button1's action, but I haven't found any helpful method for that

```py
from tkinter import *

def move():
    # my code

def stop():
    #??? 
master = Tk() 

Button1 = Button(master, #some options, command = move).pack()
Button2 = Button(master,#some options, command = stop).pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suppose you can just define a new button that will appear at some random position. And that button won't be attached to a new function won't what solve your problem?

Comment: The thing is i must only use two buttons. Button1 for doing some command, and Button2 to stop Button1's command

Comment: I suppose you could use a tuple to define that function's coordinates so that it will not change. But I think that will raise an error in your program am I wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31412683/17246406

Answer (score 0):

So this code I am going to introduce after my research will hopefully satisfy what you need. So first of all, you need a function to move buttons around and secondly, another function to stop the working of the first one's function (i.e., to prevent its movement).

So one way of doing this is to set the state of the other Buttons to DISABLED to grey them out and prevent clicks. So the one I have shown below uses this method.

```py
# Importing tkinter module
from tkinter import *

# Importing random module
import random

# Creating a tkinter window
root = Tk()

# Initialize tkinter window with dimensions 300 x 250
root.geometry('300x250')

# Stop other function
def stop():
    btn.config(state=DISABLED)

# Defining func to move on click
def move():
        x = random.randint(50,250)
        y = random.randint(50,200)
        btn.place(x=x, y=y)
    
# Creating a moving Button
btn = Button(root, text = 'Click me!',command=move)
btn.pack()

# Creating an end movement Button
endbtn = Button(root, text = 'Stop movement!', command=stop).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Now coming to the second method, you can use another function that does nothing to modify the movement button's function. An example of this is given below:

```py
# Importing tkinter module
from tkinter import *

# Importing random module
import random

# Creating a tkinter window
root = Tk()

# Initialize tkinter window with dimensions 300 x 250
root.geometry('300x250')

# Stop other function
def stop():
    btn.config(command=donothing)

# A function to do nothing
def donothing():
    pass

# Defining method on click
def move():
        x = random.randint(50,250)
        y = random.randint(50,200)
        btn.place(x=x, y=y)
    
# Creating a moving Button
btn = Button(root, text = 'Click me!',command=move)
btn.pack()

# Creating an end movement Button
endbtn = Button(root, text = 'Stop movement!', command=stop).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

And the last method is to destroy the whole button. You can use the second button to destroy the first button. An example is given for your reference.

```py
# Importing tkinter module
from tkinter import *

# Importing random module
import random

# Creating a tkinter window
root = Tk()

# Initialize tkinter window with dimensions 300 x 250
root.geometry('300x250')

# Destroy the other button
def stop():
    btn.destroy()

# Defining method on click
def move():
        x = random.randint(50,250)
        y = random.randint(50,200)
        btn.place(x=x, y=y)
    
# Creating a moving Button
btn = Button(root, text = 'Click me!',command=move)
btn.pack()

# Creating an end movement Button
endbtn = Button(root, text = 'Stop movement!', command=stop).pack()


root.mainloop()
```